# I just earned the Generalist badge…

Tags: discussion, badges

…And so did 43 other folks. [Simultaneously.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/generalist) How does that happen?

Comment: But who got it simultaneousliest?

Comment: @doppelgreener (I'm pretty sure by mentioning it first, I get dibs on having had the badge at least simultaneouslier than some other, less alert badgers, but because I'm by far the modestest fellow I know, I didn't want to rub it in.)

Comment: (Ok, I can accept this, since that is very modestiest of you.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The site itself [only just met the minimum qualifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85049) to award the Generalist badge:

> > One thing the badge doesn’t say, is that there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone. ... I don’t feel you can accurately measure a generalist until the top tag list settles down.

Approximately seven minutes ago a script ran and noticed that RPG.se finally reached 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags. Congratulations, us!

Simultaneously, everyone who had already qualified for the badge was finally awarded it.

… This is one of those badges that works *much* more as-advertised on larger sites like Stack Overflow.

---

As a point of trivia, the threshold seems to have been crossed by the “graduation” of the [movement](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movement) tag. It seems to have crossed the threshold when I edited [Can I use Lightning Lure as a grappling hook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97379/can-i-use-lightning-lure-as-a-grappling-hook) to include the tag.

Interestingly, that seems to have put the tag to *20**1*** questions, not 200, and the script didn't trigger on 200. I suspect there is an off-by-one error in the Generalist badge that actually makes it need 201 questions in the top 40 tags, rather than 200.

Update: [Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293205/is-there-an-off-by-one-error-in-the-generalist-badge) it's not a bug in the script, it's a “bug” in the original description of how it works, and >200 (i.e., 201) is correct: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258).

Comment: Programming is 1% talent, 99% hard work, and 1% avoiding off-by-one errors.

Comment: Though it really shouldn't be done, but for the purposes of seeing if there are any actual bugs with the awarding of this badge, I'm wondering what happens now if the question with the movement tag gets that tag removed, and then re-added. Will everyone's silver bade be revoked and re-awarded, or will everyone get two silver badges?

Comment: @markovchain Nothing would happen. :) Badges are never revoked and you can't earn Generalist multiple times.